# Special moves on iPhone for Street Fighter 2

Tags: ios, street-fighter-ii

Can I please get some suggestions on how to perform back,forward special moves for Street Fighter 2 on the iPhone.

For example moves like Guile's Sonic Boom with this action <- -> is near impossible and I can only get it to work about 1 in  100 times.

Other moves like anything Sagat does are reasonably easy.

Is my timing off or is this just damn hard on the iPhone?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you charging the move long enough?

Unless they changed the move requirements for the iphone, sonic boom is supposed to be hold back for 2 seconds then forward + punch.

Comment: Worked great. After all these years I need to practice timing.